# Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which has more than one SQL statement

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

Using "Database stored procedure" connector in Mule 4.2.2 for Sybase database.

1. { call XXX } - it is not working in Mule 4.2.2 studio using jconn4-26502.jar and getting below error
2. exec XXX - it is working in SQL developer tool.

   description=Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which has more than one SQL statement. For the declaration of this cursor to be legal the procedure should have a single SELECT statement clause.

   detailedDescription=Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which has more than one SQL statement. For the declaration of this cursor to be legal the procedure should have a single SELECT statement clause.

   errorType = DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
   cause=org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.QueryExecutionException

[Sybase Stored procedure issue in Mule 4.2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiAaz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by writing java code using CallableStatement

Comment: It's great you found the answer yourself, but could you provide a little more detail for people who may find this in the future?

Comment: Along with Java code, we have tried with another option to resolve this issue using DB connector itself by using below configuration.
`Driver Name:-net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
DB Protocol: - jdbc:jtds:sybase
Dependency: -
<dependency> 
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId> 
<version>1.3.1</version> 
</dependency>
Shared Library: -
<sharedLibrary>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId> 
</sharedLibrary>`

Comment: [@uday_techie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6248267/uday-techie) Thanks for sharing! one fix to your comment above is to use URL : `jdbc:jtds:sybase://<HOST>:<PORT>/<Database>` when using db connector config.